# Incrementing counter in AES CTR mode?

Tags: go, encryption, aes

While decrypting a file in AES-CTR mode, I need to increment the IV/counter by 1 for every block size bytes.

This is only to illustrate my main idea:

```
buf := make([]byte, 16)
i := 0

for {
    _, err = io.ReadFull(encrypted_file, buf)

    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)

    iv := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(iv[12:], uint32(i))
    plaintext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize)

    mode := cipher.NewCTR(block, iv)
    mode.XORKeyStream(plaintext, buf)

    i++
}
```

Is this the correct way to do it in Go? First problem I think, is the file has to be read 16 bytes at the time, which is not efficient if fetching from network, but I'm not sure how else to do it?

Comment: The Stream returned by NewCTR already increments the counter for each block (hence the name), so you should just do the obvious and wrap it with [StreamReader](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/cipher#StreamReader) to read the file. Why do you think you have to re-initialize the cipher for every block? That defeats the purpose of the block cipher mode.

Comment: You are correct. I did not understand the workings correctly.